# Conditionally adding more JSX to React component based on ternary statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I currently have quite a complex (re-used component). I basically have a scenario whereby I use the value of `renderPlanB` (equates to true or false), and if true, we add various JSX elements. My current implementation looks like this but it repeats too much code. I don't want to make them separate components as changes to the base functionality would then need to be made in both. Any ideas on a clean re-factor?

```
    return renderPlanB ? (
      <>
        {options.map(option)}
        <StyledRow>
          {variousOptions.map((opt) => (
            <StyledLabel
               variousProps={variousProps}
               variousProps={variousProps}
            />
          ))}
        </StyledRow>

        <RepeatingComponent
           variousProps={variousProps}
           variousProps={variousProps}
        >
          {errors}
          <StyledContainer>
            <StyledProgress>{index + 2}</StyledProgress>
            <StyledEnteredCountries>
              {variousOptions.map(option)}
            </StyledEnteredCountries>
          </StyledWrappingContainer>
        </RepeatingComponent>
      </>
    ) : (
      <>
        {options.map(option)}
        <StyledRow>
          {variousOptions.map((opt) => (
            <StyledLabelOptionTwo
               variousProps={variousProps}
               variousProps={variousProps}
            />
          ))}
        </StyledRow>
        <RepeatingComponent
           variousProps={variousProps}
           variousProps={variousProps}
        >
          {errors}
          <StyledRow>
            {variousOptions.map(option)}
          </StyledRow>
        </RepeatingComponent>
      </>
    );
```

As you can see, they both carry out the same logic, however, when `renderPlanB` is true, we render some additional Styled Components.

Comment: Declare the parts that differ as constants and use them inside the the JSX

Comment: Move the condition to the part that actually differs?

Comment: With this approach you seem to be plugging in and out large chunks of your components tree unnecessarily (which is not good performance-wise). I would consider above comment and focus on what is actually changing, keeping _static_ parts untouched on condition toggle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by checking the `renderPlanB` higher in the component tree (the component in the questions parent) so it looked like this:

```
{renderPlanB ? (
   <NewComponent {...sharedProps} />
) : (
   <DefaultComponent {...sharedProps} />
)}
```

I then just created a const of `sharedProps` that I spread into both components (as they shared props) and this reduced the lines of code significantly:

```
  const sharedProps = {
    prop1: prop1,
    prop2: prop2,
    prop3: prop3,
    prop4: prop4,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Contrived, but maybe try separating out...

```
return (
<>  
  <DefaultPlanComponents/>
  {renderPlanB && <PlanBComponentsHere/>}
</>
)
```